# Regex to get complete optional part if present

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to verify if a entered order number either is an original or a duplicate.

Order number can have either numbers or character and must be 13 `([A-Z0-9]{13})`

A duplicate, its sepatated by a dash and its added a single capital letter `([-]{1}[A-Z]{1})`

Given that the user can either enter the original or a duplicate order, the duplicate can be present or not, so, so far, I have this

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{13})([-]{1}[A-Z]{1}){0,1}
```

It works correctly, but I'm having an issue validating that, when the duplicate is entered, its completed and correctly

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9]{13})([-]{1}[A-Z]{1}){0,1}/.test("ABCDEFGKLM123") // true
/([a-zA-Z0-9]{13})([-]{1}[A-Z]{1}){0,1}/.test("ABCDEFGKLM123-A") // true
/([a-zA-Z0-9]{13})([-]{1}[A-Z]{1}){0,1}/.test("ABCDEFGKLM123-AA") // true. Should return false!
/([a-zA-Z0-9]{13})([-]{1}[A-Z]{1}){0,1}/.test("ABCDEFGKLM123-") // true. Should return false!
/([a-zA-Z0-9]{13})([-]{1}[A-Z]{1}){0,1}/.test("ABCDEFGKLM123A") // true. Should return false!
```

I'm having problems getting this last 3 scenarios to be validated correctly

I'm still trying to figure out how to make that, if the optional part is present, its complete and correct over here https://regex101.com/r/wU4tQ5/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some problem here.First you don't need `{0,1}` for an optional case you can simply use `?` and `[-]{1}` can be `-` also `[A-Z]{1}` to `[A-Z]`.Also you need to use start and end anchors to match your string from start to end to refuse of matching some string like `ABCDEFGKLM123-AA`

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]{13})(-[A-Z])?$
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/kD2wN2/1

Comment: @m.cekiera Welcome ;)

Comment: AWESOME!

Thanks, worked perfectly, and so simple, looks like I was missing the start and end of!

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{13}(?:[-]{1}[A-Z]{1}){0,1}$)
```

Comment: Awesome, this one worked perfectly, just like Kasramvd one also did worked. Shame I can't set both as correct answers to my question, thanks!!